# Resistance of liquids

Tags: electricity, electrical-resistance

What is the effect of temperature on the resistance of liquid conductors (like electrolytes)? I think that it should increase with rise in temperature, as, just like in metals, the ions would bump into each other more often but the reverse is mentioned in my textbook.

Comment: Near-duplicate of [Resistance of car battery](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/407818/resistance-of-car-battery#comment913429_407818).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resistance may decrease with rise in temperature as in case of electrolytes conductance is due to ions which have interionic forces. As we increase the temperature the energy is used to weaken these forces leading to increase in mobility of these ions thus increasing conductance or decreading resistance

Comment: Indeed, also in for example glass.